# schedule parse push notification from ios not updating on dashboard

Tags: ios, push-notification, parse-platform

I am using parse push notification service for my ios app.  When i'm requesting through rest api for scheduling notification i'm getting result as success from there. But no notification got sent and no record on dashboard too.

```
NSData* dataRequest = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:kNilOptions     error:&err];
    [postRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [postRequest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", dataRequest.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [postRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [postRequest setValue:@"9eMo8YwW75fFA5jh0Xnv8fvwEYgyMA32l4rB2Te5" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-Application-Id"];
    [postRequest setValue:@"qJ86vHcr9omWmDqZxA28rA67amjGZ4pJ5urj2tn2" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-REST-API-Key"];
    [postRequest setHTTPBody:dataRequest];
```

above is the method that i'm using for request.

{
    channels =     (
        global
    );
    data =     {
        alert = 321213;
        badge = Increment;
        sound = "";
    };
    installationId =     {
        "$in" =         (
            "556d28f1-b44a-4dcf-a753-13c1a2a2b1d8"
        );
    };
}

and sending above data in it.

Can any one help me to solve this problem.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i got solution data sent by me is in wrong formate.

{
    channels =     (
        global
    );
    data =     {
        alert = "Testing Done";
        badge = Increment;
        sound = "";
    };
    deviceType = ios;
    installationId =     {
        "$in" =         (
            "556d28f1-b44a-4dcf-a753-13c1a2a2b1d8"
        );
    };
    "push_time" = "2014-06-05T09:10:00Z";
}

now i'm able to schedule notofication.